# Dropdown menu in external file

Tags: html, css

I made a drop down menu using HTML and CSS. Something like this: http://sneznipark-kg.si/

How can i put a menu in external file(so that i don't need to make changes to it on every page individually)?

I could use iframes, but the problem there is, that elements that "drop  down", are only visible in iframe, not on the main page.

I found some solutions using PHP, but i cant use those, because contract with my server provider doesn't include databases (so i cant use PHP, right?).

Comment: You can use PHP without a database. Whether or not your hosting includes PHP is a different matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

How to Make Website Navigations with PHP Includes:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IMh2cGIX41g

Simple PHP/HTML navbar for a static website:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8PUIVn3NFE

As mentioned above, you should be able to use PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to jquery AND both files are on the same domain.  You can use `.load()`.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

You can use any container as a place holder.  Like a div, then load the html page into the div.  It will put the entire page into the div.  So you probably just need to add the menu part, and not the entire html markup.